# Leaving child process running after the parent exits

Tags: python, subprocess, parent-child, daemon

I want to create a child process which will run after the parent has finished.

I have tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(['myscript'])
exit()
```

The child is created, but the parent waits until the child has finished.
Instead, I want to finish quickly and let the child do the hard work in the background. Any suggestions?

Some clarifications:

- it is running on Linux (Ububntu Server 14.04)
- python 2.7 preferably
- I don't want to communicate with the child in any way. The child is totally independent process.

I need the main process to finish quickly as it will be accessed from the web. It is meant to trigger another script. The result will be sent to email later on (by the child process). So, no need for the user to wait for the answer. Just quick "ok" and then the child starts.

EDIT:
Okay. Now to be honest, even my example in this post works in the simplest case (just those 2 lines + script which sleeps for 10 seconds + writes a file => main finishes and I get a file in 10 seconds).
The actual situation is somewhat more complicated.

There is one script, which iterates over a list of scripts which all have to be executed. This main script uses subprocess.Popen with communicate() (waits for the output). This calls my "main" script which I'm asking help here. This "main" does something and then wants to run a child in background. In that context, the "main" waits for the child.

I will try to make a short cleaned up code example.

Comment: Try `subprocess.Popen(['myscript'], start_new_session=True)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Daemon might be a bit of an overkill here. Sadly, Ago doesn't mention if the spawned process has to be further controlled somehow by the user (stop, pause, pipe input/output etc.). If no control is required and the spawned process contains code that does its thing and then automatically goes to a non-existent state, you need not do something as complex as creating a daemon. The OP should provide this information so that we can evaluate what is the optimal solution in his case.

Comment: Should mention this in the comment and not just type "related". Posting links without giving information about their content and how it's related to the question at hand is not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
import os  
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, 'myscript')
```

If you only want to run the child process on Linux, Here is a another way using GNU program `nohup` like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['nohup '+'myscript'+' &'])
# or use os.system()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, then one way to do that is to use `nohup`. Note that `nohup` will also redirect the standard output to `nohup.out` which might be undesirable

```py
subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'myscript'])
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `system()` [(documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). Something like :

```
import os
os.system('myscript' + ' &')
```

The `&` at the end of a command will execute it in the background in a subshell.

Comment: This will also only work on Linux or Unix. On Windows, use `start /b myscript`

Comment: With this I can end my main program, but the "myscript" is never run.

Comment: @KevinGuan Tinkering with process management and ICP is never multiplatform to begin with (unless you use high-level abstraction such as the JVM). Take a look at this [article](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/).

Comment: @rbaleksandar Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Ago Just curious, how are you verifying that `myscript` ran?

Comment: os.system() returns the result if the process spawning has succeeded or not. But this is only on Unix system. I do believe on Windows systems `os.system()` was returning something else.

Comment: @sasankc I'm writing to a file.

Comment: Well, I don't think he wants to check the result by looking at the return value. Because, he will then have to wait until the process exists. His question specifically does not want to do this.

Comment: @Ago Okay, make sure you are using the full path of your script in place of `myscript`.

Answer (score 0):

use the following snippet which will work

```
import subprocess, os
subprocess.Popen(['myscript'])
os._exit(0)
```